# Delegate inside a thread stops a program

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I created a thread and I want to add an event in it. But when I add it, the program stops without any exception or error.

I created my thread like that :

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => fabricationchaise(nbChaises,i, newChair, chairtmp));
```

And this method `fabricationchaise` I added this following code :

```
Event("something");
```

When I'm out of the thread, the `Event("")` works.

For information, I created the event like that :

```
 public delegate void Delegate (String textActivity);
 public class Test{
     public event Delegate Event;
     ...
 }
```

In my main, I have :

```
public void modifActivity(String textActivity)
    {
        TextActivity = textActivity;
    }
```

And a set with an `Invoke` method.

So, why it doesn't work when I'm in a thread ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running that thread code and then immediately finishing the application? That is, are you calling this `Thread t1 = new Thread(...` shortly before the `Main` method finishes?

Comment: @Rob With the debug mod, I can see that the program stops in the method modifActivity. When I remove my `Event`, the program finishes normally.

Comment: What is `TextActivity`? Perhaps an exception is being thrown..?

Comment: @Rob There is no exception. This method is used to change the value of `TextActivity` (and then, call a Invoke method to change the content of a richTextBox). And as I said, out of the thread, the `Event` works, so the method `modifActivity` works

Comment: Well, yeah, but if execution is *suddenly* stopping, 9/10 times it's due to an exception that's swallowed up and not visible (since it doesn't properly propagate to the main thread). Can you try adding a `Join` immediately after starting the thread? And also, just because `modifActivity` works in a single-thread context, doesn't mean it's not broken for multiple threads, so I wouldn't rule exceptions out quite yet. `.Join` should let you see an exception if it is indeed being thrown.

Comment: @Rob Do you mean create the thread, add the event and then add the `.Join` ?

Comment: I mean something like this: `Thread t1 = new Thread(..); t1.Start(); t1.Join();`. You should hook up your event before this, though.

Comment: @Rob Ok, the program stops at the `.Join`, so it's not because of the `Event`.

Comment: Can you wrap that in a `try/catch` and put a breakpoint in your catch block? It's almost definitely an exception being thrown.

Comment: @Rob The program doesn't enter in the catch, and the program stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98410/discussion-between-erlaunis-and-rob).